# how to fix value of type 'SCNNode' has no member 'materials' in Xcode ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

so basicly I try to set green color to my cube but  I get this error :C
hope you guys can help me

here is my code:

```
func randomFloat(min: Float, max: Float) -> Float {
    return (Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (max - min) + min
}

let zCoords = randomFloat(min: -2, max: -0.2)

let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0))
cubeNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, zCoords)

let mate = SCNMaterial()
mate.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green

cubeNode.materials = [mate]

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
```

Answer (score 2):

You get that error, since only `SCNGeometry` has a property `materials`, `SCNNode` doesn't. So you have to access the `geometry` of your node to add an `SCNMaterial` to it.

```
cubeNode.geometry.materials = [mate]
```

However, since you are only adding a single material, you can also use

```
cubeNode.geometry.firstMaterial = mate
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it.